# Why does a Java Template Constraint limit the constrained type to the extended type in return statements?

Tags: java

I have code like so:

```
public class Something<T extends Thing> {

    private T theThing;

    public Something(T aThing) {
        theThing = aThing;
    }

    public T getTheThing() {
        return theThing;
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere, I write this:

```
Something something = new Something<SpecialThing>(new SpecialThing()); // SpecialThing extends Thing
SpecialThing specialThing = something.getTheThing(); // Error: getTheThing() returns object of type Thing instead of SpecialThing!
```

Why do I not get `theThing` as a `SpecialThing`, but as a `Thing` instead?

Thing class:

```
public abstract class Thing {
}
```

SpecialThing class:

```
public class SpecialThing extends Thing {
}
```

Comment: provide the Thing and SpecialThing class code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that you are using a raw type reference to your `Something`. That means that the only thing Java can say for sure is that the type returned extends `Thing`, so that is the type you are getting.

Add the type parameter like this to return a `SpecialThing`:

```
Something<SpecialThing> something = new Something<SpecialThing>(new SpecialThing()); 
SpecialThing specialThing = something.getTheThing();
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you didn't specify the type in the variable declaration. You might have instantiated it with `SpecialThing`, but that's not how you remember it.

You'll notice it works when you use this instead.

```
Something<SpecialThing> something = new Something<SpecialThing>(new SpecialThing());
```

It's the same as defining `ArrayList t = new ArrayList<String>();`. This will still be regarded as `ArrayList<Object>`, not `ArrayList<String>`.

[JavaDocs on *raw types*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).